# Conditional Aggregation of one column based on values of other in Pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark

Though I have seen one question on similar lines but it doesn't fit my purpose. So posting it here and looking forward to getting answers.
I have 2 pyspark data frames : Customers weekly spend on the product

[image]

2. Product first and last week of sales
   [image]

I need to get customers' spend in the category corresponding to each product depending on products' first and last week of sales.
For e.g 
Corresponding to Product W, since it was present only in 2nd week, so I need to consider only customers' category spend in 2nd week only
[image]

I am struggling to get my head around it but no luck. Looking for suggestions.

Comment: You could set up a db<>fiddle using Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it.  This is more complicated than I would have thought, but I think this does what you want:

```
select t1.*, t2.category_spend
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.product, sum(t1.spend) as category_spend
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 t2
           on t1.week between t2.weekstart between t2.weekend
      group by t2.product
     ) t2w
     on t2w.product = t1.product;
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, the logic is basically the same.  The `customer` isn't differentiated it the question, so it can just be included "everywhere":

```
select t1.*, t2.category_spend
from table1 t1 join
     (select t1.customer, t2.product, sum(t1.spend) as category_spend
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 t2
           on t1.week between t2.weekstart between t2.weekend
      group by t2.product, t1.customer
     ) t2w
     on t2w.product = t1.product and t2w.customer = t1.customer;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, But this won't work as category spend has to be calculated at customer level.